# Jquery menu onmouseenter and mouseleave strange behavior

Tags: jquery, hover

This is my js menu that hide/show menu item on hover...
I have menu like this one:

```
    <ul class="main">
        <li class="acro_jq_menu">
            <a href="" title="How to">How to one </a>
            <ul>
                <li>item21</li>
                <li>ite222m1</li>
                <li>item1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="acro_jq_menu">
            <a href="" title="How to">How to Two </a>
            <ul>
                <li>item1</li>
                <li>it2em1</li>
                <li>it41em1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

And this is javascript:

```
function slideMenu()  {
 var items = $('.main li.acro_jq_menu');
        items.bind({
            mouseenter: function(e) {
                $(this).find('>ul').css({
                    'opacity':0
                }).show().animate(

                {
                    'opacity':1
                },
                500);
            },
            mouseleave: function(e) {
                $(this).find('>ul').fadeOut(100, function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                })
            }
        });   
}

$(document).ready(function(){
        slideMenu();
    });​
```

Everything works fine, but sometimes when i mouse leave current `li` content inside this list item hiding too long(more than 2 seconds or so) and sometimes content not showing at all.  I think something wrong with jquery code, but i cant figure it out.

Here the link to JSfiddle example of my code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6hZuV/1/)

Comment: here is an example site, of how my menu looks and should behaive http://www.homebuilding.co.uk/   , main manu

Comment: I could not reproduce any strange behavior. (using Firefox and Chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stopping all animations on the events:

http://jsfiddle.net/6hZuV/4/

```
function slideMenu()  {
 var items = $('.main li.acro_jq_menu');
        items.bind({
            mouseenter: function(e) {
                $(this).stop(true, true).find('>ul').css({
                    'opacity':0
                }).show().animate(

                {
                    'opacity':1
                },
                500);
            },
            mouseleave: function(e) {
                $(this).stop(true, true).find('>ul').fadeOut(100, function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                })
            }
        });   
}
```

Comment: heh, yep animation is stopped and this works as i see in chrome and firefox, great :/

Comment: Was halfway through this when it was answered: http://jsfiddle.net/6hZuV/11/ just a slightly different way to do what you want and will always mean the animation starts from scratch when entered or left